# Hash function on list independant of order of items in it

Tags: c#, algorithm, hash-function

I want to have a dictionary that assigns a value to a set of integers.

For example `key` is `[1 2 3]` and `value` will have certain value.

The thing is that `[3 2 1]` needs to be treated the same in my case so hash needs to be equal, if I go with hash approach.

The set will have 2 to 10 items.

Sum of items is usually fixed so we cannot make hashcode according to sum, which is a first natural idea here.

Not a homework task, actually facing this problem in my code.

This set is basically `IEnumerable<int>` in C# so any data structure is fine to store them.

Any help appreciated. Performance is pretty important here too.

An immediate thought: we could sum up `items^2` and already get some kind of better hash, but still I would like to hear some thoughts.

**EDIT:** hmm *really sorry guys*, everyone suggests ordering, didn't come to my mind that I needed to say that actually ordering and hashing is the current solution I use and I am considering faster alternatives.

Comment: Have you considered using an ordered set as the key instead of ienumerable?

Comment: ordering is expensive so yes I have but it doesn't fit desired performance, id rather not sort 10 items before hashing them.

Comment: sorting is not bad for 10 items.

Comment: What will be the typical range of your values?

Comment: @DanielA.White well it all depends on definition of performance I guess. If I could avoid checks & swaps required to sort 10 items and hash immediately with good distribution obviously it will be better, right?

Comment: @HenkHolterman items can be between 1 and 300000 roughly, sum is between 10000 and 10000000 roughly

Comment: since ideally the key will be immutable, you could calculate it once and store the result.

Comment: had a thought like that key is indeed immutable, however this lists/sets are generated somewhere else , they arent flyweights and storing a calculated hash key is going to be useless cause it will not get called more than 1 time usually.

Comment: @HenkHolterman also items are often distinct (like 95%+ of the time)

Comment: With a 300k range and small sets (~10) I would stop worrying and simply sum the items. You're not going to completely avoid collisions anyway and the rate won't be bad.

Comment: sum is usually a constant , like I say in question: Sum of items is usually fixed, so adding them up is guaranteed collision. It can simply be in that range, but at the time function operates it will usually deal with a big bunch of sets with same sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically all of the approaches here are instantiations of the same template. Map x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>n</sub> to f(x<sub>1</sub>) op … op f(x<sub>n</sub>), where op is a commutative associative operation on some set X, and f is a map from items to X. This template has been used a couple of times in ways that are provably good.

- Choose a random large prime p and a random residue b in [1, p - 1]. Let f(x) = b<sup>x</sup> mod p and let op be addition. We essentially interpret a set as a polynomial and use the [Schwartz–Zippel lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz-Zippel_lemma) to bound the probability of a collision (= the probability that a nonzero polynomial has b as a root mod p).
- Let op be XOR and let f be a randomly chosen table. This is [Zobrist hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zobrist_hashing) and minimizes in expectation the number of collisions by straightforward linear-algebraic arguments.

Modular exponentiation is slow, so don't use it. As for Zobrist hashing, with 3 million items, the table f probably won't fit into L2, though it does set an upper bound of one main-memory access.

I would instead take Zobrist hashing as a departure point and look for a cheap function f that behaves like a random function. This is essentially the job description of a non-cryptographic pseudorandom generator – I would try computing f by seeding a fast PRG with x and generating one value.

EDIT: given that the sets all have the same sums, don't choose f to be a degree 1 polynomial (e.g., the step function of a linear congruential generator).

Comment: Bloom filters could be thought of as another "hash function" for sets, though this certainly is not their primary use. Here, op = bitwise OR and f(x) is a sparse 0-1 bit array.

Comment: @Henk Holterman I have no idea what the scare quotes are for (provable is provable), but I put in a note about not using a degree-1 polynomial for f.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `HashSet<T>` and  [`HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475.aspx), which returns an `IEqualityComparer<HashSet<T>>`.

Comment: just had a thought like this . but there is a chance it sorts items or isn't very performant I believe. I don't know which algorithm it uses, do you?

Comment: checked the code, doesn't look very good to me : foreach (T local in obj)
        {
            num ^= this.m_comparer.GetHashCode(local) & 0x7fffffff;
        }

Comment: @ValentinKuzub, it uses `XOR` of all elements (.NET 4.0)

Answer (score 2):

I think what is mentioned in this paper would definitely help:

http://people.csail.mit.edu/devadas/pubs/mhashes.pdf

Incremental Multiset Hash Functions and Their Application to Memory Integrity Checking

Abstract: We introduce a new cryptographic tool: multiset hash functions. Unlike standard hash functions which take strings as input, multiset hash functions operate on multisets (or sets). They map multisets of arbitrary ﬁnite size to strings (hashes) of ﬁxed length. They are incremental in that, when new members are added to the multiset, the hash can be updated in time proportional to the change. The functions may be multiset-collision resistant in that it is diﬃcult to ﬁnd two multisets which produce the same hash, or just set-collision resistant in that it is diﬃcult to ﬁnd a set and a multiset which produce the same hash.

Comment: From your description it appears that main focus is to have function that is cumulative in a way that if set is increased in size, hash doesn't need to be fully recalcuated. I am not sure it applies to my problem or?

Comment: I would think that crypto-grade hashes are too slow.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: another important feature of the hashing functions mentioned in this paper is that they are defined on sets instead of strings, hence making the values invariant from the ordering of elements in the set, IMHO

Comment: @Per: Yes, that is indeed a problem...btw, are you Per Austrin?

Comment: @derekhh No, I'm not Per Austrin.

Answer (score 2):

I think your squaring idea is going in the right direction, but a poor choice of function. I'd try something more like the PRNG functions or just multiplication by a large prime, followed by XOR of all the resulting values.

Answer (score 1):

If the range of the values in `key` happens to be limited to low-ish positive integers, you could map each one to a prime number using a simple lookup, then multiply them together to arrive at the `value`.

Using the example in the question:

```
[1, 2, 3] maps to 2 x 3 x 5 = 30
[3, 2, 1] maps to 5 x 3 x 2 = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: sort the items in the list, then hash that.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the numbers and select a sample from predetermined indices and leave rest as zero if current value has less numbers. Or you could xor them, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like

```
public int GetOrderIndependantHashCode(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    return (source.Select(x => x*x).Sum()
            + source.Select(x => x*x*x).Sum()
            + source.Select(x => x*x*x*x).Sum()) & 0x7FFFFF;
}
```

Comment: remember that we are battling sort approach. we got a lot of multiplications and summations going on here, sorting might outmatch this.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Override `GetHashCode`. In it, sort your collection, call and return `ToArray().GetHashCode()`.